# find -name -path

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command-line, find

I have a some tree.

```
.
├── 1
│   └── a
│       └── script.a.sh
├── 2
│   └── a
│       └── script.b.sh
...
└── a
    └── script.sh
```

And I need to find `script.*.sh`. I execute `./a/script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

path="/tmp/test"

readarray files < <(find ${path} -path  "*/a/script.*.sh")

if [ ${#files[@]} -ne 0 ]
then
  for file in "${files[@]}"
  do
    echo ${file}
  done
fi
```

Output:

```
/tmp/test/1/a/script.a.sh
/tmp/test/2/a/script.b.sh
```

It's worked script!

But if I change find command to `find ${path} -path  "*/a" -name "script.*.sh"` the script does output nothing.

My logic find all files with pattern `/tmp/test/*/a/script.*.sh` what I say with `find ${path} -path  "*/a" -name "script.*.sh"`.

My questions that remain at the moment:

1. What does `find ${path} -path  "*/a" -name "script.*.sh"` command do in real?
2. There is debug mode in the `find`? I mean how does it understand what I say to it (example: path(s) where it will search, without `find . -name "*te.st*"`, just `./*/*te.st*`).
3. Can `-name`, `-path` live on the same command line (need cases, examples, explanation) or they mutually exclusive? Or can we say `-path` extended version of `-name`?

Guys, yes I can use `man` and `google`. In these source I do not find full answers at all my questions either.

Comment: @JaromandaX It works! Thanks a lot for variation, but unfortunately the comment answer no one questions. It solve the problem but my questions do not find solve this problem. It's here above. But thanks again.

Comment: @JaromandaX Unfortunately, you are wrong again, I will not explain why either. Please, read all questions carefully again.

Comment: `It works` yet, I'm wrong? .... AGAIN? Sorry, what planet are you from?

Comment: @JaromandaX :) Ok, It seems I have to give you more full explanation why your comment don't suit me. Understand, there are people who need everything to work. They aren't interesting how it work. And there are people who ask the question why it works and why it doesn't works. They are searching more global solve. So that there are no questions in the future.
If simple this question about `why`, and you comment `here is worked variant`.

Comment: On other words, I was not interesting worked variant, I have had it. I was interesting why it does not work. That is why I said: `...but unfortunately the comment answer no one questions...` and `...Please, read all questions carefully again...`. Unfortunately I will not be able to give you more understandable explanation, if you will not understand this explanation. Sorry.
p.s. I'm from Earth and you? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if I change find command to `find ${path} -path  "*/a" -name "script.*.sh"` the script does output nothing.

Indeed, it must not.  A file  matching the predicate `-path  "*/a"` cannot also match the predicate `-name "script.*.sh"`.

> My logic find all files with pattern `/tmp/test/*/a/script.*.sh` what
> I say with `find ${path} -path  "*/a" -name "script.*.sh"`.

You seem to be assuming that the value of `$path` is `/tmp/test`.  In that case, it's unclear to me why you are making this so complicated.  Since you can exactly describe the paths you want via a glob, I would be inclined to leave `find` entirely out of the picture:

```
files=("${path}"/*/a/script.*.sh)
```

But if you want to do it with `find`, then I don't see the point of combining `-name` and `-path` for this case.  As you already observed, your original `find` command does the job.  And it's simpler and clearer.

Alternatively, you could move the partial-path matching to the starting-point list:

```
find ${path}/*/a -maxdepth 1 -name  "*script.*.sh"
```

> 1. What does `find ${path} -path  "*/a" -name "script.*.sh"` command do in real?

It searches for files in the subtree rooted at `${path}` whose paths (starting with `${path}`) match the pattern `*/a`, and whose basenames match the pattern `script.*.sh`.  Each in full.  The paths of any files matching both criteria will be printed, but the conditions cannot both be satisfied for the same file, so nothing will be printed.

> 2. There is debug mode in the `find`? I mean how does it understand what I say to it (example: path(s) where it will search, without `find . -name "*te.st*"`, just `./*/*te.st*`).

POSIX does not specify any debug facilities for `find`, but inasmuch as you have tagged `linux` and `ubuntu`, you are almost certainly using the GNU findutils version of `find`.  This implementation *does* have debug facilities, which are documented on [its manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).  You are looking for the `-D` option.  It's unclear how helpful you would find it, but for maximum debug information you could add `-D all` to your `find` command, before the starting-point list.

> 3. Can `-name`, `-path` live on the same command line (need cases, examples, explanation) or they mutually exclusive? Or can we say
>    `-path` extended version of `-name`?

Yes, of course they can be used together, and occasionally it even makes sense to combine them.  But the points that may have confused you are that

- they are *independent*, and
- `-path` tests the *whole* path, not just the directory part.  Perhaps this is what you mean when you ask whether `-path` is an extended version of `-name`.

Your attempt at combining them failed because your `-path` predicate does not actually match the files you want to select.  But this would work:

```
find ${path} -path  "*/a/*" -name "script.*.sh"
```

Also, combinations that use the `-o` connective (meaning "or") instead of default or explicit `-a` ("and") may find more use, or combinations in which one or both of the predicates is negated via `-not`.

Comment: On other word I said `find` to find directory and file - i.e. to find one entry which is a directory and a file at the same moment, but it's impossible, that is why result is empty. Am I right?

Comment: I understand `-path` is extended version of `-name`. There are any cases where `-name` are useful then `-path`? On other words for what exist `-name` if exist `-path`?

Comment: Not exactly.  `-path` predicates can match any directory entry -- regular files, directories, special files.  Same for `-name` predicates.  In your example, each file considered by `find` is tested against both the `-path` predicate and the `-name` predicate.  These cannot both match for any given file, not because they are inherently incompatible, but because of the specific path and name patterns you provide.  This answer already provides an example of them working together.

Comment: This answer also already discusses more plausible scenarios for using `-name` and `-path` together.

Comment: It is not suitable for this question but anyway. I wanted to use something like this `files=("${path}"/*/a/script.*.sh)` at first. Can you advise me where I can read about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bash is pretty well documented in [its man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) or in [its reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).  I'm not sure what else to say but that the statement you now ask about uses a combination of Bash features that, collectively, set the value of shell variable `files` to an array whose elements are the paths to existing files that match the given shell pattern (supposing that it matches any files at all or that you have the `nullglob` shell option enabled).

Comment: Yeah, I have asked about `glob`, not `array`. You have right understood.

Answer (score 4):

The `-path` argument in the GNU version of `find` specifies a pattern which is applied to the full path of the object being visited, including the starting directory.

The pattern is a pattern, but does not treat slashes as special. For instance the path `a/b/c/d` matches the pattern `a*d`.

It is similar to the pattern matching in the shell `case` statement:

```
$ case a/b/c/d in a*d ) echo match;; esac
match
```

rather than the pattern matching in pathname expansion.

```
$ echo a*d # will not match an a/b/c/d file accessible in this directory!
```

This for instance:

```
find /etc -path '*.conf'
```

will match and print `/etc/foobar/foobar.conf`. When it encounters that path, that path will match the pattern.

Thus:

1. Q: What will `find ${path} -path  "*/a" -name "script.*.sh"` do?

   A: It will not find anything. Because `-path` matches paths ending in `/a`, whereas `script.*.sh` matches directory entries that cannot possibly be `a`.    The `-path` and `-name` predicates are joined by an implicit logical AND and so the result is empty.
2. The starting places are optional in `find`; you can use `find -name '*.txt'` without `find . -name '*.txt'`. The shell syntax `./*/*te.st*`, if used as an unquoted argument to `find` will be expanded by your shell using filename expansion. or possibly stay as-is, if it doesn't match anything.
3. Q: Can `-path` and `-name` live on the same command line.

   A: Of course, but if they are combined with "and", and conflict, the results may be empty.  `find -path X -name Y` means `find -path X -a -name Y -a -print`: if the visited path does not match `X`, **and** the directory entry being visited matches `Y`, the path will be printed. If no path which matches `X` ends in a name that matches `Y`, then the `-print` predicate (implicit or explicit) cannot be reached: nothing can be printed.